# How can I resolve file naming conflicts between Git branches?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

1) Branch `firstBranch`:

rename `/frontends/myfrontend/utils/myfile.js` to `/frontends/myfrontend/utils/myfile2.js`

---

2) Branch `secondBranch`

rename `/frontends/myfrontend` to `/frontends/myfrontend2`

---

Now I want to merge `firstBranch` into `secondBranch`, while keeping both renames applied (since one is over a parent directory, and the other over a child file).

Rename strategies (`find-renames` and `rename-threshold`) are dealing only on identifying changed content being renamed, but I think this is a different case. The content is the same, it is just that git does not allow me to solve the merge by applying both renames.

How should I deal with this? I know git does not understand about directories, nevertheless I think it is a real use case.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to combine these, if Git detects all the renames from the merge-base commit to the tip commit of `secondBranch` *and* the (single) rename from merge-base to tip of `firstBranch`, you will get a *rename/rename conflict*.

The merge will stop, having done all the *rest* of the renames and combinations as appropriate.  Your job is to *finish* things.  There is only one thing to finish, at least from this particular conflict: you must choose the desired name for this file.

Write the desired file contents under the desired name—this may require using `mv` to rename the file in the work-tree, and/or editing the file if the contents are not what you want—and then use `git add` and `git rm` as needed / appropriate to update Git's index to store the possibly-updated file under the desired name.  You have now resolved the rename/rename conflict.

Resolve any other conflicts as well, so that all conflicts are resolved, and Git's index contains the snapshot you would like as the merge result.  Then run:

```
git merge --continue
```

to finish the merge.